# Writing to file with Groovy(Grails) fails for some lines (broken lines)

Tags: file, csv, groovy, append

I am performing some mass writing in a .csv file using Groovy. More specifically, I have a Quartz job that is running and creates some Map messages that get sent to a RabbitMQ queue. The queue is being consumed by 10 consumers and results in producing some lists of Strings. For each element in the List I just write it in a pipe separated .csv file. The actual service that has the method that writes to the .csv file, is a standard (singleton) transactional grails service. When I log the lines to be written, everything's fine, but in the file, some lines are "broken". The way I am writing is:

```
def writeRowsToFile(List<String> rows, File file) {
  rows.each {row->
    file.append("${row}\n")
  }
}
```

Initially I was using:

```
file.withWriterAppend {out->
  out.write(row.toString())
  out.newLine()
}
```

and got the same thing as well...

If it was something wrong it would fail for all the lines. Could it be some kind of race condition, concurrency or I don't know what else issue?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: By "broken" I mean that not all the string is written in the line, on some iterations. The line is half written. I have attached the code I am using to write into the file. the String objects I am writing, from what I see in the logging are fine, but when they get written in the file a few of them fail to be fully written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be doing it the second way, ie:

```
def writeRowsToFile(List<String> rows, File file) {
  file.withWriterAppend {out->
    rows.eachWithIndex { row, idx ->

      // It's probably \n chars in your strings
      if( row ==~ /.*[\n\r]+.*/ ) {
        println "Detected a CRLF char in rows[$idx]"
      }

      out.writeLine row
    }
  }
}
```

However, you say it might be "some kind of race condition"

Are multiple threads writing to the same file?

If not, it is more likely that your `row` data has `\n` characters in it

Comment: I hadn't thought of that actually, that my row data might have newline chars in them. Will have to check it! If it's that you saved me from jumping from the roof (and made me remember that I am a bit dummy)

Comment: Fingers crossed that's it :-)  That regex should detect them if they're there.  And don't beat yorself up!  I've done far worse in my time ;-)

Comment: I already changed the code and will give it a try. Thank you very much for your help. I will come back with the results of this exercise.

Comment: No \n chars detected :-( And I am still getting "broken" lines, which do not seem to have any continuation with the right above lines. I think it has something to do with the Queue consumers writing all on the same file. Should I add some Thread.sleep() there? It will make it really slow...

Comment: `Thread.sleep` won't help you, (though it might make it look like it has helped, it really won't have).  You can either `synchronize` the `writeRowsToFile` method, or look into some sort of concurrency framework like GPars http://gpars.codehaus.org/ -- This page here should help I think: http://ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-gpars/index.html#N10407

Comment: So, I adding @Synchronized on the method, seems to have done the trick! :-) Now, the only thing left is to test it on the production environment where we have 2 servers and 2 grails app instances, writing on the same file on an NFS. This might be tricky, I am not sure how the RabbitMQ consumers behave in this case. Thank you so much for your help, as soon as I verify that everything's working as expected I will mark your answer as correct. You really saved me from going crazy (at least for today :-) )

Comment: So, it seems like the file was created and populated successfully, all lines are OK. @Synchronized was the thing to do! Thank you very much, you are a life saver!

Comment: @herc GLad I could be of help!  Good luck with it all :-)