# Writing into file under NFS in Grails app using Quartz and RabbitMQ

Tags: java, grails, csv, rabbitmq, quartz-scheduler

We have a Grails app, that uses RabbitMQ for passing messages. The architecture we have for the production environent is:
- 2 web servers, let's say web1, web2. Both of them run an instance of a grails app
- a RabbitMQ server is installed on only one of the servers, web1
- In the RabbitMQ configuration in the Grails app, we have 10 consumers (per application instance)

We have a Quartz job that creates some messages and passes them to the queue, and we have a consumer service that handles the messages getting in the queue.
1. How can we define which server (application instance)should execute the Quartz job? I assume there's only one server running the Job and Quartz is taking care of that.
2. How can we define which server handles the messages from the queue?

The problem is, that the methods that consume the queue messages, eventually write some rows in a .csv file, which is under NFS.

Initially we had some [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104074/writing-to-file-with-groovygrails-fails-for-some-lines-broken-lines), with the actual writing in the .csv file. There were some "broken", half-written rows in the file, but we resolved this by adding @Synchronized on the method that wrote in the .csv file. Now the issue is, that some rows, just don't get written at all.

Any ideas? I am not sure whether this is a programming issue, and if so how could it be resolved, or if it is an architectural issue.

**UPD**:@Olexandr
Initially I had (example)
`def getStringsToWrite(File file, List someOtherList) {
  def stringsList = []
  someOtherList.each {
    def someString = "someString"
    stringsList << someString
  }
  writeRowsToFile(file, stringsList)
}`

@Synchronized
def writeRowsToFile(File file, List stringsList) {
  file.withWriterAppend {out->
    stringsList.each {row->
      out.writeLine row
    }
  }
}

And it did was not working "properly"

Now, I changed the code to something like:

```
class someServiceClass { //singleton
  LinkedBlockingQueue csvWritingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue()
```

def getStringsToWrite(File file, List someOtherList) {
    def stringsList = []
    someOtherList.each {
      def someString = "someString"
      **csvWritingQueue.put(someString)**
    }
    writeRowsToFile(**file**)
  }

@Synchronized
  def writeRowsToFile(File file) {
    file.withWriterAppend {out->
      **while (!csvWritingQueue.isEmpty()) {**
        **out.writeLine csvWritingQueue.poll()** 
      }
    }
  }
}

Please let me know if you need any additional info. I tried to keep it at a high level perspective, but I will be more than happy to include some code in the post.

Thanks in advance,
Iraklis

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing that it could happen because some threads(handlers) are suspending due to timeout while waiting on synchronized lock.

But this is only my gues and it depends on application architecture(how did you organize queues, handlers, etc.)

**UPD:**
I have some sort of idea. Writing to CSV file is not thread safe and that's why you are using synchronization lock. And maybe that's why some threads are suspended while waiting. But we could solve it easily by creating **WriteManager** class. This class should have [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) instance so handlers will not invoke *write* method directly but they will put data to be written in the *Queue*(if queue is full they have to wait but if queue will be big enought they have not wait at all) and manager class will poll queue in *infinite loop*(of course it will be finite and controled by a *flag*) and write data to CSV file. So when you have to start writing\managing process you just starting *WriteManager* and when no more writing is needed you just switch off the polling loop(actually loop shouldn't stop when you stop it manually but it should to poll all objects from queue and only than stop).

**UPD2:** Does you invoke *getStringsToWrite* multiply times ? This is very basic example of what i mean but you could easily extended it or even fully rewrite.

```
class someServiceClass { //singleton
  LinkedBlockingQueue csvWritingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue()
  def currentWriter = null
  def writerThread = null

def getStringsToWrite(List someOtherList) {
    def stringsList = []
    someOtherList.each {
      def someString = "someString"
      csvWritingQueue.put(someString)
    }
  }


@Synchronized
  def writeRowsToFile(File file) {
    file.withWriterAppend {out->
      while (!csvWritingQueue.isEmpty()) {
        out.writeLine csvWritingQueue.poll() 
      }
    }
  }

 def write (File file) {
   if (writerThread == null) {
   currentWriter = new Runnable() {
      boolean isRun = true
      public void run() {
         while(isRun) {
            if(!csvWritingQueue.isEmpty()) {
               writeRowsToFile(file)
            }
           try {
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
           }catch(e){
            //e.printStackTrace()
           }
         }
      }
   }
   writerThread = new Thread(currentWriter)
  writerThread.start()
  }
 }

def stop() {
  if (currentWriter != null) {
    currentWriter.isRun = false;
   try {
    writerThread.join();
   }catch(e){
    //e.printStackTrace()
   }
  }
 currentWriter = null;
 writerThread = null;
}

   }
}
```

I hope it would help you.

[BackgroundThread plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/background-thread) - has nice example of background worker.

Comment: Hi Olexandr,  Thanks for your reply!  I actually thought the same thing, that some thread maybe times out, but did not find any sufficient way of controlling that or any resolution this problem.

Comment: @herc, i think you allready has some sort of thread pool implementations so why not to track this pool ? Just log any changes in pool. Or you could create some sort of marker in your thread(handler) objects and then just examine this markers when work is done. Marker is set to true if handler succesfully writen all content and false if it does not. Anyway, there are a lot of different hacks/hooks/implementations but the main point is that you have to track how handlers behave.

Comment: @herc, read updated part of answer. background-thread plugin has good example of such queue manager.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sounds like the right thing to do. I am giving it a try right now, and I will come back with the results of this exercise.

Comment: @Olexandr, tried to pass the strings to be written, via a LinkedBlockingQueue, still does not work. Maybe I am doing something wrong, any ideas?

Comment: @Olexandr answering your question about whether I invoke the getStringsToWrite multiple times, **yes, I do**. I am now going through your code. Thanks again!

Comment: I am afraid your code won't work for my case. Currently, I am passing some messages through RabbitMQ to the consumer service, and for every message I end up creating a String which I want to print. The String creating method is called many times, for each batch of objects passed through the queue. So, what I am trying to do, is at the end of processing each batch, I would like to "flush", to write all the Strings in the file.

Comment: I have started to believe that the issue is because I am writing on a file under NFS. Locally, for one application instance writing on a local file it works fine. Having two application instances writing on an NFS file seems not to be working really well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to configure quartz in a cluster?
http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your reply. The problem is not at the Quartz level. Currently, we have a vanilla Quartz installation which means that the job runs on just one server, which is fine, exactly what I want. The issue is that the job creates some messages that get passed to the RabbitMQ, get consumed by both of the servers, and end up in writing on the same file, under NFS. And it is there, that the whole thing gets messed up. I tried all kind of thread control, locking etc., it did not work. Apparently because we have two seperate instances of the application.

Comment: So, writing to the file, from both the servers, did not work. What I needed, is to be able to control, that only one server will write on the file. The only way I can have this right now, is with Quartz jobs. So, what I did is, I changed the initial job, to end up in writing the file rows in the DB, which has better concurrency handling, and then I have another job (running just on one server), writing all the DB table rows, one by one into the file. Kinda messy ha? I know, but couldn't think of anything faster and really needed to get this thing fixed.

Comment: What you implemented does not exactly sound messy....I think that alot of people do this in practice.  It seems your using the db as a kind of semaphore.  I've seen this quite a bit.

Comment: Actually I am just using the DB as a temporary storage space for the rows to be written in the file, DB concurrency handling works out of the box. But yes, it works like a charm, no issues since we deployed that fix.